# How to display alphabets dynamically in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android application. In that I need to display radiobuttons dynamically based on a particular size. I am able to display the radio buttons with 1,2,3.

like

```
1. text1
2. text2
3. text3
```

But how can I display the radio buttons like below

```
a. text1
b. text2
c. text3
```

Any help will be thankful

Comment: google it Already asked in stackoverflow ..here(https://www.google.co.in/search?q=add+radio+button+dynamically+android&rlz=1C1LENP_enIN539IN539&oq=dynamically+add+radio+button+androi&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l3j62l2.10947j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a RadioGroup in the layout file

```
<TableRow>
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/radiobuttons">
    </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>
```

and then programmatically add buttons to it and set the text as you want it instead of numbers:

```
public void makeRadioButtons(Vector tmpVector, int i,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp)
{
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
    rb.setText((String) tmpVector.elementAt(i));
    //rg is private member of class which refers to the radio group which you can find   by id.
    rg.addView(rb, 0, lp);

}
```

Hope this helps.